# Coldfusion 8: identify repeating values in a column and counting number of times it appears

Tags: coldfusion

I need to query a table in an SQL DB using CF 8, look at a specific column for repeating values, and count how many times it occurs. **I am really new to CF** and for the life of me can't figure out how to do this. I can query the DB and specify results from the referenced Column, but the rest is frustrating!

So, if I had the following results from the query for a specific column:

```
APPLE
APPLE
GRAPE
PEAR
APPLE
PEAR
APPLE
```

I know I could do a query of a query, but I would have to know what the values (fruits in this case) would be before hand. Or so I believe.

Basically, what I need is to be able to run the CFM and have it spit out:

- APPLE: 4
- PEAR: 2
- GRAPE: 1

Not knowing what the values might be beforehand.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you looking to get it sorted by number of fruit descending?

Comment: It would be better if it was sorted descending, but not required.

Comment: @user2378766 - See [@Ben 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16528231/104223). His example demonstrates how to order the results by the number fruits (descending).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfquery name="qMyFruits">
SELECT fruitName, COUNT(fruitName) AS instances
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY fruitName
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="qMyFruits">
<p>#qMyFruits.fruitName# : #qMyFruits.instances#</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Chris, Thanks! This worked wonderfully. If you could have only seen the excruciatingly long lines of CF I had written; from loops, valueLists, etc. Just... wow!

Comment: This query is very fundamental.  Since you had to ask, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Thanks Dan, will check it out. I guess I need to find a "CF for Dumbies" as well.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in SQL.  You could create a CFLOOP and then build a struct or other logical mechanism to count each fruit, but this is far easier:

```
<cfquery name="FruitSummary" datasource="myDatasource">
    SELECT
        FruitName, Count(FruitName) as Count
    FROM
        FruitBasket
    GROUP BY
        FruitName
    ORDER BY
        Count(FruitName) DESC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't always have direct access to the SQL server so wanted to pull the data with an cfm.

Comment: Of course I meant through a CFQUERY, but Chris's answer is near identical :-)